# Allow Anonymous User to Access Form

Tags: forms, 8

I'd like to create a form with Drupal that all users can access, but every time I try to access the form without being logged in, I get this error:

```
Access denied

You are not authorized to access this page.
```

How can I allow all users to access the form?

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: @IvanJaros What specific information would you need in order to solve the issue?

Comment: First, what kind of form you are talking about ? A node form, a contact form, a custom form that you implemented in PHP? Did you configure the permissions/route access (in case of a custom form) and if so, how exactly?

Comment: It's a contact form made with the form module in Drupal.

Comment: What's the actual name of the module? https://www.drupal.org/project/form is a Drupal 6 module. Is it the Contact module? Your own module?

Comment: Show us your code. Is this your own customized module?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear before. I'm using the Contact module that comes packaged with Drupal 8.

Answer (score -1):

Select People -> Permissions, scroll down and adjust the permissions of Contact.

Comment: I adjusted the permissions and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use users' personal contact forms needs to be set to be accessible by anonymous users.